# Am I using ReactiveCocoa the "right" or most "purely functional" way in this Document class?

Tags: swift, reactive-cocoa

## Introduction

I am still learning both swift and `ReactiveCocoa`, and instead of directly applying it to one of my projects, I have instead worked a few hours on implementing a silly form with it.

My form has these elements:

- Email
- Password
- Confirmation
- Reset button
- Submit button (not implemented)

There are three validators/indicators:

- Email address format validator
- Password strength indicator
- Passwords match validator

I am overall pretty happy with the ease by which I was able to accomplish all of this. I mean, wow! `ReactiveCocoa` is amazing.

The fact that I can program a password strength indicator with such little code is a testament to both the `ReactiveCocoa` library and the frameworks on top of which it is built.

But... I am sure the code can be better, perhaps significantly so. So I am asking for your help in identifying any places or means by which I can make better use of `ReactiveCocoa` in terms of reducing unnecessary side effects, utilizing other features, etc.

In particular I am interested to know:

- Built-in alternatives to `DynamicProperty` (I am using some code not shown to achieve its effect some times, code that I would imagine is similar to `DynamicProperty` implementation but worse). People say not to use `DynamicProperty` so what else can I use?
- Why I need `Action` *and* `CocoaAction`
- Whether I should keep my `DocumentViewModel` "pure" in the sense of being a `POCO` with basic data types, not `MutableProperty`

## DocumentViewModel

```
public class DocumentViewModel {

    public let propertyForEmailAddress = MutableProperty<String>("")
    public let propertyForPassword = MutableProperty<String>("")
    public let propertyForPasswordConfirmation = MutableProperty<String>("")

    public let actionReset = Action<Void, Void, NoError> {
        return SignalProducer.empty
    }

    public var cocoaActionReset: CocoaAction!

    init() {
        cocoaActionReset = CocoaAction(actionReset) { _ in
            self.propertyForEmailAddress.value = ""
            self.propertyForPassword.value = ""
            self.propertyForPasswordConfirmation.value = ""
        }
    }

}
```

## Document

```
class Document: NSPersistentDocument {

    @IBOutlet private var uiTextFieldEmailAddress: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet private var uiTextFieldPassword: NSSecureTextField!
    @IBOutlet private var uiTextFieldConfirmPassword: NSSecureTextField!

    @IBOutlet private var uiLevelIndicatorPasswordStrength: NSLevelIndicator!

    @IBOutlet private var uiButtonClear: NSButton!
    @IBOutlet private var uiButtonSubmit: NSButton!

    private let viewModel: DocumentViewModel

    override init() {
        self.viewModel = DocumentViewModel()
        super.init()
    }

    private func bindViewModel() {

        viewModel.propertyForEmailAddress <~ uiTextFieldEmailAddress.x_textDidChangeSignalProducer
        uiTextFieldEmailAddress.x_textProperty <~ viewModel.propertyForEmailAddress.producer

        viewModel.propertyForPassword <~ uiTextFieldPassword.x_textDidChangeSignalProducer
        uiTextFieldPassword.x_textProperty <~ viewModel.propertyForPassword.producer

        viewModel.propertyForPasswordConfirmation <~ uiTextFieldConfirmPassword.x_textDidChangeSignalProducer
        uiTextFieldConfirmPassword.x_textProperty <~ viewModel.propertyForPasswordConfirmation.producer

        uiTextFieldEmailAddress.x_textDidChangeSignalProducer.start({s in print(s.value!) })

        bindViewModel_ButtonResetAction()

        bindViewModel_EmailAddressValidator()
        bindViewModel_PasswordConfirmationBackgroundColor()
        bindViewModel_PasswordStrengthIndicator()
    }

    private func bindViewModel_ButtonResetAction() {

        uiButtonClear.target = self.viewModel.cocoaActionReset
        uiButtonClear.action = CocoaAction.selector

    }

    private func bindViewModel_EmailAddressValidator() {

        DynamicProperty(object: self.uiTextFieldEmailAddress, keyPath: "backgroundColor") <~
            self.viewModel.propertyForEmailAddress.producer
                .map({(s) -> Bool in return s.isEmail()})
                .map({ (ok) -> NSColor in return (ok) ? NSColor(calibratedRed: 0, green: 1, blue: 0, alpha: 0.25) : NSColor(calibratedRed: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.25)});

    }

    private func bindViewModel_PasswordStrengthIndicator() {

        uiLevelIndicatorPasswordStrength.ui_propertyForIntValue <~ viewModel.propertyForPassword.producer.map { (s) -> Int in
            return s.characters.count
        }

    }

    private func bindViewModel_PasswordConfirmationBackgroundColor() {

        uiTextFieldConfirmPassword.ui_propertyForBackgroundColor <~
            viewModel.propertyForPassword.producer.combineLatestWith(viewModel.propertyForPasswordConfirmation.producer)
                .map({(s1, s2) -> Bool in return s1 == s2 })
                .map({ (ok) -> NSColor in return (ok) ? NSColor(calibratedRed: 0, green: 1, blue: 0, alpha: 0.25) : NSColor(calibratedRed: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.25)});

    }

    override func windowControllerDidLoadNib(aController: NSWindowController) {
        super.windowControllerDidLoadNib(aController)

        bindViewModel()
    }
```